# Scrolling until Element is out of display in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to scroll until an item is now longer visible in the browser window. I tried the following:

```
int currentscroll = 0;
IWebElement ArticleTop = firedrive.FindElementByClassName("article-photo");
while (IsElementVisible(ArticleTop) == true)
{
    currentscroll = currentscroll + 100;
    js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0," + currentscroll + ");");
    Thread.Sleep(250);
}
```

I got this from an answered question on Stack Overflow:

```
public bool IsElementVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return element.Displayed && element.Enabled;
}
```

There are no errors but it continues to scroll until it reaches the bottom of the page which is not what I intended. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Does the page have jQuery?

Comment: You can't use `.Displayed` for this case. You have to calculate the view port and position of the element.

Comment: @Buaban Mhmm got a good point I'll see what their is to do . Thanks.